How to Opentelemetry metrics are get in OpenSearch dashboard?
I installed OpenSearch Dashboard , Dataprepper and Opentelemetry to use with Helm chart.
So I installed OpenSearch and OpenSearch Dashboard. For generating automatic index in the Opensearch dashboard, I installed the "Dataprepper" with this configuration in value.yaml code.
Dataprepper configuration code in value.yaml:
  config:
    otel-metrics-pipeline:
      workers: 8
      delay: 3000
      source:
        otel_metrics_source:
          health_check_service: true
          ssl: false
      processor:
        - otel_metrics:
            calculate_histogram_buckets: true
            calculate_exponential_histogram_buckets: true
            exponential_histogram_max_allowed_scale: 10
            flatten_attributes: false
      sink:
        - opensearch:
            hosts: ["https://opensearch-cluster-master.default.svc.cluster.local:9200"]
            username: "admin"
            password: "TadhakDev01"
            insecure: true
            index_type: custom
            index: ss4o_metrics-otel-%{yyyy.MM.dd}
            bulk_size: 4

Created an index in the Opensearch dashboard with this name "ss4o_metrics-otel-%{yyyy.MM.dd}".
and I installed Opentelemetry with this configuration in value.yaml code.
Opentelemetry configuration code in value.yaml:
config:
  exporters:
    otlp/data-prepper:
      endpoint: my-data-prepper-release.default.svc.cluster.local:21891
      tls:
        insecure: true

    debug: {}
  extensions:
    # The health_check extension is mandatory for this chart.
    # Without the health_check extension the collector will fail the readiness and liveliness probes.
    # The health_check extension can be modified, but should never be removed.
    health_check:
      endpoint: ${env:MY_POD_IP}:13133
  processors:
    batch: {}
    # Default memory limiter configuration for the collector based on k8s resource limits.
    memory_limiter:
      check_interval: 5s
      limit_mib: 512 
      spike_limit_percentage: 25
  receivers:
    kubeletstats:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
      # collection_interval: 30s
      metrics:
        container.cpu.time:
          enabled: true
        container.cpu.utilization:
          enabled: true
        container.memory.available:
          enabled: true
        container.memory.usage:
          enabled: true
        k8s.node.cpu.time:
          enabled: true
        k8s.node.cpu.usage:
          enabled: true
        k8s.node.memory.available:
          enabled: true
        k8s.node.memory.usage:
          enabled: true
        k8s.pod.cpu.time:
          enabled: true
        k8s.pod.cpu.usage:
          enabled: true
        k8s.pod.memory.available:
          enabled: true
        k8s.pod.memory.usage:
          enabled: true
        
    k8s_cluster:
      node_conditions_to_report: [Ready, MemoryPressure]
      allocatable_types_to_report: [cpu, memory]
      metrics:
        k8s.container.cpu_limit:
          enabled: true
        k8s.container.cpu_request:
          enabled: true
        k8s.container.memory_limit:
          enabled: true
        k8s.container.memory_request:
          enabled: true
    zipkin:
      endpoint: ${env:MY_POD_IP}:9411
  service:
    telemetry:
      metrics:
        address: ${env:MY_POD_IP}:8888
    extensions:
      - health_check
    pipelines:
      logs:
        exporters:
          - debug
        processors:
          - memory_limiter
          - batch
        receivers:
          - otlp
      metrics:
        receivers: [hostmetrics]
        processors: []
        exporters: [otlp/data-prepper]


After I installed this Opentelemetry, my index "ss4o_metrics-otel-%{yyyy.MM.dd}" total size got automatically increased.
this is the index image:
enter image description here
these are all metrics that show in the "Discover" in OpenSearch dashboard.
this is the "Discover" image :
enter image description here
but in the OpenSearch dashboard "Metrics" there are no metrics available in the "Metrics" form
this is the "Metrics" image :
enter image description here
So I want, all index metrics to be in OpenSearch dashboard "Metrics".
